# How to run all scripts in specific zoom size in chrome selenium?

Tags: java, selenium, selenium-webdriver, automated-tests, selenium-chromedriver

The website isn't look same on mac and windows. So i'm looking for the capabilities/options for the chrome which set certain zoom size and all scripts get executed in same size.

I'm aware of Firefox but not found for chrome

```
FirefoxProfile profile = new FirefoxProfile();
profile.setPreference("layout.css.devPixelsPerPx", "0.9");
```

Answer (score 1):

This ChromeOption did it for me for both linux and macOS:

```
options.addArguments("--force-device-scale-factor=1");
```

These are the other options I have on in order to run my tests via Jenkins on a linux server.

```
options.addArguments("--ignore-certificate-errors");
options.addArguments("--disable-popup-blocking");
options.addArguments("--incognito");
options.addArguments("--disable-dev-shm-usage");
options.addArguments("--allow-insecure-localhost");
options.addArguments("--window-size=1920,1080");
options.addArguments("start-maximized");
options.addArguments("enable-automation");
options.addArguments("--disable-infobars");
options.addArguments("--disable-browser-side-navigation");
options.addArguments("--disable-gpu");
options.addArguments("--no-sandbox");
```